# Como exibir o conteúdo aos poucos quando utilizado a função print sem quebra de linha?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**PYTHON 3**

```
import time
for i in range (1, 11):
    time.sleep(1)
    print (i)
```

**RESULTADO:** *Saída na tela a cada segundo.*

Com base nas instruções acima, toda vez que a condição for verdadeira será impresso um resultado na tela a cada segundo. Até aí tudo bem.

Porém quando utilizo **end=""**, o *loop* só imprime meu resultado quando a condição não é mais verdadeira, ou seja, ele não imprime a cada segundo e sim, somente quando termina.

```
import time
for i in range (1, 11):
    time.sleep(1)
    print (i, end=" ")
```

**RESULTADO**: *Saída na tela somente no fim do loop*.

MORAL DA PERGUNTA: Como eu poderia imprimir um resultado A CADA SEGUNDO sem quebra de linha?

Comment: Sou novo no ramo, também não sabia sobre o FLUSH, logo justifica a duplicata rsrs. Obrigado á quem me direcionou ao link pois resolveu minha dúvida :)